# SUM in a column based on the value in SKU field of the current record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am migrating a tool I am building from excel to SQL due to its size (file size and complexity is making it exceptionally slow).  I have a list of SKUs in various DCs with a count of each. I would like to create a SUM based on TotalOnHand of each SKU at each site.  Essentially "add up the values from other warehouses where the SKU equals the current record's SKU."  I can then take this value as a denominator to get a percentage of total inventory is at each warehouse. I am learning SQL for the first time for this project.

Current query:

```
    SELECT  Material, Plant, Unrestricted + [Unrestricted VOI] as TotalOnHand
    FROM [ATP_Snapshot].[Tables].[INVENTORY_REPT]
    WHERE Unrestricted >0
    AND [Unrestricted VOI] >0
    AND (
    Plant = 'US23'
    OR Plant = 'US27'
    OR Plant = 'US46'
    OR Plant = 'US49'
    )
    ORDER BY Plant, Material
```

Function I am trying to create.  I am stumped where it ends.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION Inventory.PercentOfTotal (@TotalOnHand integer)
    RETURNS decimal (4,3)
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @PercentTotal decimal (4,3);
    SET @PercentTotal = @TotalOnHand/(SELECT SUM(@TotalOnHand) WHERE
```

Also, I am getting an error indicator where I understand the name goes (i.e. Inventory.PercentOfTotal).  This is what I am trying to name my function.

Comment: Is `Inventory` a schema or catalog? If not, a dot is a tricky character; I suspect you can enclose the whole name in brackets, as in `[Inventory.PercentOfTotal]`.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  Removing the "Inventory." did not change it.  I still get the red squigglies.

Comment: FYI, an `IN` would be much more succinct than those `OR`s.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the IN statement.  Also, I think the reason I am getting the error mark on my name is because I haven't finished the statement.

Comment: _of each SKU at each site. Essentially add up the values from other warehouses..._ Site means Plant means warehouse? And what is a "DC"? Requirements are difficult to write - and more difficult to understand when terminology does not match code/schema.

Comment: Do you want quantites for a SKU for all DCs on the same row, or on separate rows?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.  DC is a distribution center.  We also call them sites, warehouses, and plants.  Different databases we have use different terminology for the same thing.   @Charlieface: I don' know at the moment.  At some point I need to use these in further calculations for sales order fulfilment.  As in removing stock from two warehouses based on the percent each warehouse holds for a specific SKU.  This will not happen in practice, but is just a tool for DC managers to use for planning.  Not sure which will be best for those further calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to show your results.

If you want each `Material` and `Plant` combination on a separate row then you need a window function. Note the use of windowing over an aggregation, `SUM(SUM())`.

```sql
SELECT
  ir.Material,
  ir.Plant,
  SUM(ir.Unrestricted + ir.[Unrestricted VOI]) AS TotalOnHand,
  SUM(ir.Unrestricted + ir.[Unrestricted VOI]) * 1.0
    / SUM(SUM(ir.Unrestricted + ir.[Unrestricted VOI])) OVER (PARTITION BY ir.Material) AS PctOnHand
FROM Tables.INVENTORY_REPT ir
WHERE ir.Unrestricted > 0
  AND ir.[Unrestricted VOI] > 0
  AND ir.Plant IN ('US23', 'US27', 'US46', 'US49')
GROUP BY
  ir.Material,
  ir.Plant
ORDER BY
  ir.Material,
  ir.Plant;
```

Or if you want them all on the same row then you need conditional aggregation, aka a pivot. Note the use of `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to prevent repetition of the calculation, you can also do that in the query above.

```sql
SELECT
  ir.Material,
  ir.Plant,

  SUM(CASE WHEN ir.Plant = 'US23' THEN v.Total END) AS TotalOnHand_US23,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ir.Plant = 'US23' THEN v.Total END) * 1.0 / SUM(v.Total) AS PctOnHand_US23,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ir.Plant = 'US27' THEN v.Total END) AS TotalOnHand_US27,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ir.Plant = 'US27' THEN v.Total END) * 1.0 / SUM(v.Total) AS PctOnHand_US27,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ir.Plant = 'US46' THEN v.Total END) AS TotalOnHand_US46,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ir.Plant = 'US46' THEN v.Total END) * 1.0 / SUM(v.Total) AS PctOnHand_US46,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ir.Plant = 'US49' THEN v.Total END) AS TotalOnHand_US49,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ir.Plant = 'US49' THEN v.Total END) * 1.0 / SUM(v.Total) AS PctOnHand_US49

FROM Tables.INVENTORY_REPT ir
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    ir.Unrestricted + ir.[Unrestricted VOI]
) ) v(Total)
WHERE ir.Unrestricted > 0
  AND ir.[Unrestricted VOI] > 0
  AND ir.Plant IN ('US23', 'US27', 'US46', 'US49')
GROUP BY
  ir.Material
ORDER BY
  ir.Material;
```

Comment: This got me where I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your function will also require two input paramaters (one for the total across all plants and one for the total per plant). Functions are also typically slow as they process "row-by-agonizing-row" (check out Jeff Moden's RBAR for further explanation) so I wouldn't really use it here but if you want to learn about them then you should create one and test it.

Instead of a function I'd use the OVER clause for summing across various partitions.

The code would look something like this:

```
  SELECT  
        distinct(Material)
        ,Plant
        ,sum(Unrestricted + [Unrestricted VOI]) OVER(Partition By Plant) as TotalOnHandPerPlant
        ,sum(Unrestricted + [Unrestricted VOI]) OVER(Partition By Plant)/sum(Unrestricted + [Unrestricted VOI]) OVER()*100 as PercentOnHandPerPlant
        ,sum(Unrestricted + [Unrestricted VOI]) OVER() as TotalOnHandAllPlants
    FROM [ATP_Snapshot].[Tables].[INVENTORY_REPT]
    WHERE 
        Unrestricted > 0
        AND [Unrestricted VOI] > 0
        AND Plant in ('US23','US27','US27','US46','US49')
    ORDER BY 
        Plant
        , Material
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go.  Looks like it will do what I need.

Comment: This did not work.  The list only contained unique SKUs.  So I got a list of SKUs at one DC followed by a list of completely different SKUs at the next DC.  There were no SKUs listed at both DCs.  In addition, the counts and percentages were at the warehouse level, not the line item level.  For all the SKUs at each plant, the total on hand, total by plant, and percent by plant were all the same. (Plant = DC = warehouse)

Comment: The code is a general approach. The OVER clause will do what you want but you'll have to tweak it to fit your specific case.

Comment: Ok I'll keep looking into it, thank you. I'm very good with excel, but am new to SQL.

Comment: If you still run into problems edit your post and include the table structure with actual data in it. This way we know exactly what you're working with.